# React.js - REF undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I test the following code I receive a console error that `newText` is undefined, am I declaring the val var correctly or am I missing something?

```js
val = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[newText]);

renderForm: function() {
        return (
            <div className="note">
                <textarea ref="newText" defaultValue={this.props.children} className="form-control"></textarea>
                <button onClick={this.save} className="btn btn-success btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></button>
            </div>
        )
    },
```

Comment: val = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[newText]); is called in another function?

Answer (score 2):

`newText` here needs to be either a string (`"newText"`) or should use dot notation instead. Using just `newText` means you're trying to read the value of a variable with that name (which will return `undefined`).

Change:

```js
this.refs[newText]
```

To:

```js
this.refs["newText"]
```

Or:

```js
this.refs.newText
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late to answer this but I came across the same problem.

I added and update the following sources:
src= "https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js">
src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js">

It worked for me.

Hope you already found a solution for this.
Cheers!

Comment: src= "https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"
src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"

Answer (score 0):

use `this.refs.newText` rather than `this.refs[newText]`.

Comment: I did try this but receive the following "TODO: Save not Value[object HTMLTextAreaElement]"

I then also tried this.refs.newText.value but still no joy